# Why does selecting all tables from postgres gives different results based on syntax used

Tags: postgresql, psql

If I log into postgres and switch to the postgres database, when I check for tables with this command I get nothing back:

```
postgres=# \c postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=# \dt+
Did not find any relations.
```

However if I do a select on the DB tables I do see that the tables are there:

```
postgres=# SELECT *
postgres-# FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
postgres-# WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND
postgres-#     schemaname != 'information_schema';
 schemaname |   tablename    | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity
------------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
 pgagent    | pga_jobclass   | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_job        | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_jobagent   | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_jobstep    | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_schedule   | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_exception  | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_joblog     | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
 pgagent    | pga_jobsteplog | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
(8 rows)
```

Why do I get nothing when I use `\dt+` but I can see the tables using a select statement?

Comment: In `psql` do `show search_path;`. You will find that the schema `pgagent` is not in it. You have two choices: 1) Do `\dt+ pgagent.*` 2) Change your `search_path` to include the schema.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will help [LINK](http://www.postgresonline.com/special_feature.php?sf_name=postgresql83_psql_cheatsheet)

```
\d [NAME] describe table, index, sequence, or view
\d{t|i|s|v|S} [PATTERN] ("+" detail) list tables/indexes/sequences/views/system tables
\da [PATTERN] list aggregate functions
\db [PATTERN] list tablespaces (add "+" for more detail)
```

use \dt+ *

the * to match all as the command needs a pattern

Comment: Cool. That did it! Thanks.

Comment: That's great. Keep going :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `pgagent` schema is not on your `search_path`. `\dt` will only show those tables that you can access without schema qualification.